# React not inserting span in client code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

First of all, I'm new to react and recently I worked through this [tutorial on tweet live stream](http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2015/09/28/building-a-real-time-twitter-stream-with-node-dot-js-react-dot-js-and-redis/).

Long story short, I wanted to add a link to each tweet following their text. To do so, I simply added props to the tweet item that contained a url and username.

When I view the site, the links are there, then they immediately disappear.

In the console, i get a warning of: "React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server"

The cause of the error here is that the server renders the list items as `<li react id...> <span react-id ...>`, whereas the client renders as `<li react-id ...> Text here with no span tag </li>`

Why is the client not wrapping the list item content in a span, as react is supposed to do. The text is inserted as a prop `{this.props.text}` if that matters.

I can provide some code, but I'm not sure what would be helpful, it is all very basic. The tweet item render() return is as follows:

```
return (
  <li className="list-group-item">{this.props.text}<a href={this.props.url}>{this.props.user}</a></li>
);
```

the server render is as follows (nodejs/express):

```
  var markup = React.renderToString(Tweets({ data: tweet_list.reverse() }));
  console.log(markup);
  res.render('index', {
    markup: markup,
    state: JSON.stringify(tweet_list)
  });
```

**EDIT**

Excerpt from server markup (one list item):

```
<li class="list-group-item" data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.1.$651">
  <span data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.1.$651.0">RT @JeffLindner1: Law enforcement has reopened all mainlanes of I-10 at White Oak Bayou except 1 west bound lane. # houwx</span>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/KPRC2/status/658219790318698496" data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.1.$651.1">KPRC2</a>
</li>
```

Excerpt from Client/view source:

```
<div id='view'><div data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk" data-react-checksum="1889651106">
  <h1 data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.0">Tweets</h1>
  <ul class="tweets list-group" data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.1">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.1.$0">
      <span data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.1.$0.0">RT @EdwardEgrosFox4: Cole Beasley gets comforted by Jason Witten after botching the punt return. https://t.co/jF9MxRN9BV</span>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/FOX4/status/658431262240059392" data-reactid=".21kkf2bdurk.1.$0.1">FOX4</a>
    </li>
```

So the span IS there. Yet the end of the warning reads:

```
(client) ".21kkf2bdurk.1.$0">RT @EdwardEgrosFox4:
(server) ".21kkf2bdurk.1.$0"><span data-reactid="
```

**EDIT 2**

So, when I examined the output html, the only difference was that the server rendered html sent along as its initial state (loads old tweets) via a script tag
 `<script id="initial-state" type="application/json">{{{state}}}</script>`
So from here, I instantly got it working by removing the passed along state, making the links appear, but this may cause a lack of persistence. I will need to test to be sure. What would the best way to handle this `initial-state`? Update it in the client, or remove it completely?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: On the snippets your data reactid's look different.. Which could make it redraw everything to the Dom. Look at the comment I posted about printing the exact outputs before and after and make sure they are the same first

Comment: Hey John, I partially figured out what was wrong, I'll update my post if you could please take a look

Comment: Ok I edited with a potential solution. I believe you need to add that script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is this

```
return (
    <li className="list-group-item">
        <span>{this.props.text}</span>
        <a href={this.props.url}>{this.props.user}</a>
    </li>
);
```

if you manually wrap it in a span react will obviously not wrap it in an additional span and it will always be there.

in general I think its a much better practice to wrap anything that is going to have an 'automatic' span with a span specifically. that way nothing is 'magically' happening in your code and you can have specific desired results every time

**Remember** if you are making changes you have to re-compile your source to see the changes take effect aka run your build process `gulp` / `grunt` / `duo` ... etc.

EDIT:

after your updates it looks like you forgot to add that script tag to your html. if you look [Here](http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2015/09/28/building-a-real-time-twitter-stream-with-node-dot-js-react-dot-js-and-redis/) the html includes that script tag (search for `<script id="initial-state"`). It looks like you need to include that on your page. react doesn't know what to do when there are missing nodes like that so it redraws everything to the DOM.

Comment: Hmm, this is so strange.. I thought this would fix it! But it didn't. For whatever reason, the console is insisting that the client HTML is still missing the span. It is apparently getting stripped. An excerpt from the warning: "(client) =".6pntflc3y8.1.$0">tweet_text_here....
 (server) =".6pntflc3y8.1.$0"><span data-reactid="...."

Comment: can you post snippets of what it actually looks like on the server side aka `console.log(markup);` as well as the html markup on the client (inspect the element)

Comment: Certainly, I'll add it to the main post

Comment: @TrésDuBiel also look at this bug report. theres some helpful tips in there for comparing the html before and after to see if / what is different https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/issues/69

Comment: John, for some reason, running `gulp react` fixed all problems. If you could add a remark to your answer as to why, I will mark it correct. Thank you for all of your help

Comment: @Tres you can just mark it as accepted since running gulp probably included the span that wasn't there and made it work.. I'll add a note when I get home to be sure to re compile things with gulp :)